# iOS unable to load views

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to navigate from one view to another on touch of a button using iOS 5.0.

The code I am using

```
- (IBAction)Actionlogin:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@" login button has been pressed");
       NSLog(@"In init");
        test_details *aSecondPageController=[[test_details alloc]initWithNibName:@"test_details" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:NO];
      }
```

I have two xib files `test_details_iPhone.xib` and `test_details_iPad.xib`

Inside my testdetails.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"it is coming here in second view");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    NSLog(@"it has been returned ");
    return self;


}
```

LOGs

```
2013-04-25 11:06:17.191 app_gototest[3067:207]  login button has been pressed
2013-04-25 11:06:17.194 app_gototest[3067:207] In init
2013-04-25 11:06:17.195 app_gototest[3067:207] it is coming here in second view
2013-04-25 11:06:17.196 app_gototest[3067:207] it has been returned
```

The view is not getting loaded onto the view. I suppose I am missing something.

**application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** in `appDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

** I am trying Jasper Blue's approach**

```
argc    int 1
argv    char ** 0xbfffed2c
*argv   char *  0xbfffee44
```

**In appDeleagte.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        UINavigationController* navigationController; 
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"     bundle:nil];
            navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]         initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
        } else {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad"     bundle:nil];
            navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
        }
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to move from iphone's xib to ipad's xib??

Comment: no..
I am writing app for both iPhone and iPad.
from iPhone 1st view to iPhone second
from iPad 1st view to iPad second

Comment: @onkar: May i know template type of your app? Is it Navigation based or Tab based?

Comment: What does your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate look like?

Comment: U want load to TestDetailViewController when u click on button right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks OK, so it must be that self.navigationController is nil. . . Have you set up a navigation controller?

For your code to work, your current UIViewController needs to be contained within a UINavigationController. . . you can set up the UINavigationController as the root view controller in your application delegate as follows:

```
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController* navigationController; 
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"     bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc]         initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad"     bundle:nil];
        navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**NB: You could clean the above code up a little, but you get the picture, which is that you have to set the root view controller to be a navigation controller, like this:**

```
 self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

You could also make a custom root view controller if you like, but the above will let you achieve what you're trying to do - UINavigationController will be used as the navigation system throughout your app.

Comment: Set up a navigation controller as shown above. . . To prove that your self.navigationController is nil, try NSLog(@"My nav controller %@", self.navigationController); ;)

Comment: @onkar, your code is different from his. He has `navigationController` below your `self.viewController`. He also sets the `rootViewController` as `navigationController`.

Comment: Sorry for my negligence . I have added these lines, but now I am getting SIGBART.
I have replace `navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];` with `navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];` since viewController was showing me error.

Comment: Show us your updated code (setting the nav controller) and the SIGBART log. . . . PS, I've updated the answer to make it more clear - check the updated NB point.

Comment: Are you now getting the error on start-up or when pushing the second controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation controller is nil. So replace your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method with

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
      self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    UINavigationController *navcontroller = navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navcontroller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Now you have a navigation controller so the call to push method on the self.navigationController should push the second controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
- (IBAction)Actionlogin:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@" login button has been pressed");
     NSLog(@"In init");
     test_details *aSecondPageController=[[test_details alloc]initWithNibName:@"test_details_iPhone" bunndle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:NO];
  }

 // test_details_iPhone.xib and test_details_iPad.xib
 //Change initWithNibName@"test_details" with test_details_iPhone or test_details_iPad
```